# Proof that $2^m+1$ is a prime number if $m=2^k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I prove that $$2^m+1,m\in \mathbb{N}$$ is a prime number, if
$$m=2^k, \text{for one k} \in \mathbb{N}$$

What I tried:

If $m=2^k$ then $1\mid m$ , $m\mid m$ and $2\mid m$.

That means for:$$2^{(2^k)}$$ that $1\mid 2^{(2^k)}$, $2^{(2^k)}\mid 2^{(2^k)}$, $2\mid 2^{(2^k)}$
but $$2\nmid 2^{(2^k)}+1$$

Comment: This is false. For example, $2^{2^5}+1$ is not prime. Perhaps you meant: "If $2^k+1$ is prime, then $k$ is a power of $2$"?

Comment: Note that it is not in general true that $2^{2^k} + 1$ is a prime. However, it can be shown that  _if $2^m + 1$ is (an odd) prime_, then $m= 2^k$. Is that what you want?

Comment: well then maybe i will give it a tryf or your scenario.Can you give an advice on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot prove that because it is not true. If $m=2^5$, then $2^m + 1$ is not prime.

Comment: It is not because it's false, that one can't prove it (only a side remark)

Comment: @Jonathan I don't understand that remark. The statement is false. You (presumably) cannot prove false statements. So... What's your point?

Comment: What I meant is just that when you can prove a statement it does not directly imply that you can't prove its negation (unless you assume that the axioms you are using are consistent). You can say though that if a statement is true of the naturals, then it is not false, which makes a slight difference.

Comment: @Jonathan OK, I get you. Yes, of course. But I think everybody on this site assumes the axioms are consistent (that's why I said presumably). Because if they are not, why bother with anythig, since everything is true.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint for proving that the contrary argument is true**

WLOG, for any *odd* natural number $m$, a polynomial of the form $x+1$ divides $x^{m}+1$ with zero remainder.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to mention that this hint applies to proving the converse.

Comment: @pjs36 Yes, you are right - perhaps I should add that slight (but vital) piece of information.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers of the form, $2^{2^{n}} +1$ are called Fermat numbers. They were all though to be prime for a long time until Euler found out that $641$ divides $2^{2^{5}}+ 1.$.
These numbers are quite interesting. They are all relatively prime to each other, and since each number of this series generates new factors, it implies there are infinite primes ! It is a very simple proof of infinite proofs. Let me know if the question is to prove that any two Fermat numbers are relatively prime and I'll put down that proof here.

Comment: You are missing a couple "+1"s. ($2^{2^n}+1$ and $2^{2^5}+1$.)

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Thanks!